# Cannot search post by taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, ajax

I'm trying to search posts by a taxonomy value, the problem is that the query doesn't return anything, this is my code so far:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'zoacres-property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property-region',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => array('Lazio (IT)'),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This is the post record stored in the db:

**wp_posts**

```
 id    | post_title  | post_type
 30081      test         zoacres-property
```

the taxonomy `property-region` have that content:

**wp_terms**

```
term_id | name 
   62      Lazio (IT)
```

**wp_term_taxonomy**

```
term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy 
       62             62      property-region
```

**wp_term_relationships**

```
object_id | term_taxonomy
    30081       62
```

why my query isn't returning anything?

**UPDATE**

output of `$query->request`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  0 = 1
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'zoacres-property' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

if I change the query as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'zoacres-property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(            
            'taxonomy' => 'property-region',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 2
        )
    )
);
```

I get as output:

```
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2)
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'zoacres-property' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

where `2` is the id of `Lazio (IT)`, the post is published with that `taxonomy` linked. No idea why this doesn't return anything

Comment: What's the output of `echo $query->request;` ? Are you sure there are no typos in your code?

Comment: @SallyCJ I have updated the question with the output, I can't see any taxonomy reference why?

Comment: It's probably because WP couldn't find the term. Try using `'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => array( 'put slug here' )` instead of querying by the term *name*.

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried as follows: `'taxonomy' => 'property-region',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array('lazio-it')` but no results

Comment: What's the `echo` output now? Does it look good? And do you actually have published posts in that post type? Try also `get_posts( $args )` - does it return any results?

Comment: @SallyCJ I have updated the question with the new ouput, the post is published and the method `get_posts($args)` didn't returned anything, just:  `array (0) {}`

Comment: Even after using the term ID and using `get_posts()`, you still get no results?? That's weird, but you can try deactivating all plugins.

Comment: @SallyCJ yep I deactivated the plugins and works now, really weird situation, some plugins has created some conflict with that code. Just a thing: is possible use the like operator for the taxonomy name? Thanks for your precious help

Comment: No, `LIKE` is not supported - see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/__construct/).